# Java does using .split to split an array of Strings into smaller arrays create duplicate array names?

Tags: java, arrays, split

Please reference the following image I created which I think will help clarify my question.  The color coding is to help identify the elements in each array.

https://ibb.co/cbvscXc

I'm just learning Java and trying to understand the solution to a practice exercise.  I have a .CSV file that the Java program reads and I have two arrays.  One array has the headers, the other has the values stored as Strings initially (converted to Doubles later because the actual numbers in the problem are Doubles).

However, when the code is run that splits "lines" array, doesn't this create multiple arrays with duplicate names as shown in the picture?

The code seems to say, in plain English, "For each String element in the "lines" array, split the string wherever there is a comma and store each of those new strings as an element in a String array called "values"."

Or does it only create one new array called "values" that has 20 separate elements?  If that is the case, then I don't understand how the counter ("cnt") in the second for-each loop knows how to cycle back to the first header after the 5th header.

So assuming the first guess is correct, wouldn't that cause an issue having duplicate array names with different values in each array?  How does the second for-each loop know which "values" array that I want to iterate over?  How does it know to iterate over ALL the "values" arrays?

Or is something else happening that I'm not understanding?  The video I'm learning from didn't really explain it clearly :/

EDIT to add the code blocks per requests

We start with two arrays, lines array and headers array:

```
lines Array ["1,2,3,4,5","6,7,8,9,10","11,12,13,14,15","16,17,18,19,20"]

headers Array ["Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"]
```

And then on the lines array we run:

```
for(String line : lines) {
String[] values = line.split();}
```

which, if I understand correctly, should create four new **permanent** arrays, basically chopping up the one large array of four elements into four new arrays with 5 elements each, as listed below:

```
values Array ["1","2","3","4","5"]
values Array ["6","7","8","9","10"]
values Array ["11","12","13","14","15"]
values Array ["16",17","18","19","20"]
```

The reason I understand these to be permanent and not "forgotten" after each iteration through the loop as one comment suggested, is that each of these arrays is further iterated upon in the second for-each loop where we add a header to each value, effectively creating a list of HashMaps, with each array having a header for each value in that specific array.  This doesn't happen until after the first for-each loop finishes running, so how could it go back and add the headers if the arrays were forgotten?

The second for-each loop in code blocks:

```
int cnt = 0;
HashMap<String, Double> headerValueMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String value : values) {
    double dval = Double.parseDouble(value);
    headerValueMap.put(headers.get(cnt), dval);
    cnt++;
}
```

which creates the new HashMap:

```
headerValueMap [{Open=1, High=2, Low=3, Close=4, Volume=5}, {Open=6, High=7, Low=8, Close=9, Volume=10}, etc...]
```

Edit:  I've been looking but still have not been able to find an answer to this question.

Comment: Kindly dont add the images , instead add the code for better help on SO

Comment: The first time through the for-loop, values holds a reference to the first array of five strings. The second time through the loop, values holds a reference to the second array of five strings, etc. Each time, the previous array is "forgotten."

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code as text here to go along with the image.

Comment: Updated to add code blocks and add some more clarifying thought process

Comment: Still looking for help on this one, please..

Comment: _"which, if I understand correctly, should create four new permanent arrays"_ — No! In `String[] values = line.split();` the variable named `values` is _local_ in [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) and is disposed of and re-created each time through the loop. When the loop is finished and you exit from the braces `{ ... }` then the variable doesn't exist at all. It is most certainly _not_ "permanent". You need to understand _scope_, which I linked in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the result of the split; you need to save it somewhere.

Try something like this:

```
List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
     String[] values = line.split();
     table.add(values);
}
```

Or better, create a `List<List<String>>`.